# ClassCastException Android, with SerializedObject[]

Tags: android, android-intent, classcastexception, serializable

Sorry for the title,

I want to pass an Array of an selfwritten class through an intent.
This is what the Sender Code looks like:

```
private void publishResults(int result, DienstplanDatenreihe[] row, String action)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(WorkingCode.TABLE, row);
    intent.putExtra(WorkingCode.RESULT, result);
    intent.putExtra(ACTION,action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

This is what the receiver code looks like:

```
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    DienstplanDatenreihe[] row =  (DienstplanDatenreihe[]) extras.getSerializable(WorkingCode.TABLE);
```

And here comes the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to HelperCode.DienstplanDatenreihe[]
```

And i dont know why... anyone else on the internet does it this way.
[Note: My DienstplanDatenreihe contains only Strings and a String[] ]

Answer (score 1):

`DienstplanDatenreihe` is probably a custom class that does not implement `Parcelable` and hence Android cannot pass it via an `Intent` by default. You will have to make your class implement the [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface.

Comment: DienstplanDatenreihe is a custom class that implements Serializable, you can pass Data via Serializable or Parcelable, i have quonquert the same error with parcelable

Comment: Using `Serializable` is strongly discouraged in Android. Please post how you implemented `Parcelable`.